# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^1\arctan(1-x+x^2)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate
$$\int_0^1\arctan(1-x+x^2)dx$$
What I did: First I assume 
$$I=\int_0^1\arctan(1-x+x^2)dx=\int_0^1\arctan((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4})dx$$
Since the function is symmetric about $\frac{1}{2}$, as $f(\frac{1}{2}+t)=f(\frac{1}{2}-t)$,
$$I=2\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\arctan((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4})dx$$
Since $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$, I get $I$ as 
$$I=2\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\arctan(x^2+\frac{3}{4})dx$$
The *integration by parts* method, here seems hectic. Does anyone know how to evaluate this integral, in a different way, or ahead of whatever point I've reached?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\tan^{-1}(1-x+x^2)dx &= \frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{1-x+x^2}\right)dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^1 \left(\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(x-1)\right)dx \end{align}$$
That should simplify everything.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use this technique, using trigonometric formulae to evaluate this integral easily.